# Unable to Post comments to blog post with Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a blog for a project and I am having problem getting my comments to post to the back end.

My code is as follows:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from products.models import Category


class Post(models.Model):
    """Model to create blog posts"""
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    """Model to handle user comments"""
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Post, Comment


class PostForm(ModelForm):
    """
    Form to allow site owner to create a new blog post
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'body', 'image']


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    """Form to handle user comments"""
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_comment(request):
    """Method to add comments to a blog post"""
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_id)
    comments = post.comments.all()

    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    template = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'new-comment': new_comment,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }    
    
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_blog, name="blog"),
    path('<int:post_id>/', views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
    path('add_post/', views.add_post, name="add_post"),
    path('edit_post/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name="edit_post"),
    path('delete/<int:post_id>/', views.delete_post, name="delete_post"),
    path('add_comment/', views.add_comment, name="add_comment"),
    path('delete/comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.delete_comment, name="delete_comment"),
]
```

Could anyone see where I am going wrong please? I have been playing around and getting different type of name and value error and am not getting any further forward.

**Current template**

```
                        <div id="comment-input">

                            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                
                            <form action="{% url 'add_comment' %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="w-100 mb-2">
                    
                                    {{ comment_form | crispy }}
                   
                                    <button class="form-control btn btn-black border border-black rounded-0" type="submit">Submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>  
                            {% endif %}

                        </div>    

                        <div class="comment-wrapper">
                            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

                                <div id="comment-details">
                
                                    <div id="comment-author">

                                        {{comment.author}} - {{comment.created|timesince}} ago
                        
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="comment-body">
                                        {{comment.body}}
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div id="delete-comment">
                                    {% if request.user == comment.author %}
                                        <a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}" class="text-danger">Delete Comment</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>

                                <hr>

                            {% endfor %}
                
                        </div>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I'm getting a NameError at present "/blog/add_comment/name 'post_id' is not defined" along with "/workspace/island-flowers/blog/views.py, line 106, in add_comment
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_id) "

Comment: ah right, yes: you are doing `get_object_or_404(Post, post_id)` but `post_id` is not defined

Comment: maybe you want to change the url to `<int:post_id>/add_comment/` and accept `post_id` arg in the `add_comment` view function?

Comment: Hi anentropic, thank you for replying. No joy with that attempt unfortunately, I'm now getting a reverse match error: NoReverseMatch at /blog/18/

Reverse for 'add_comment' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/add_comment/$']

Comment: I had changed the URL to path('<int:post_id>/add_comment/', views.add_comment, name="add_comment"),   and the view to def add_comment(request, post_id):. Was that the intention?

Comment: yep that was correct, you made progress but now also need another change - in your template `{% url 'add_comment' %}` now needs to specify a post id too, the syntax would be `{% url 'add_comment' post_id %}` or whatever var you have in your template that holds the relevant post id

Comment: Unfortunately that brought me back to having a name error again....it's so close i can nearly taste it lol

Comment: it helps if you can post the error (and learning to read and interpret the errors is a useful skill to develop) also the full (or more of the) code of the template, and what is the name of the template?  is it `blog/post_detail.html` and you are rendering the page and then submitting to same page?

Comment: Thankfully I've just been able to sort it...In addition to your advice I also had to set the comment author in the Post request. Its now working perfectly. Thank you for all of your time and assistance in helping me sort this.

Comment: no prob, glad you have it working